# Restangular extendModel on new object

Tags: restangular

Restangular offers a feature, extendModel, which lets you add functionality onto objects returned from the server.  Is there any way to get these methods added to an empty / new model, that hasn't yet been saved to the server?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same thing but didn't find an example. Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
models.factory('User', function(Restangular) {
    var route = 'users';
    var init = {a:1, b:2}; // custom User properties
    Restangular.extendModel(route, function(model) {
        // User functions
        model.myfunc = function() {...}
        return model;
    });
    var User = Restangular.all(route);
    User.create = function(obj) {
        // init provides default values which will be overridden by obj
        return Restangular.restangularizeElement(null, _.merge({}, init, obj), route);
    }
    return User;
}
```

Some things to be aware of:

- Use a function like _.merge() instead of angular.extend() because it clones the init variable rather than simply assigning its properties.
- There is a known issue with Restangular 1.x that causes the Element's bound data to not be updated when you modify its properties (see [#367](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/367) and related).  The workaround is to call restangularizeElement() again before calling save().  However this call will always set fromServer to false which causes a POST to be sent so I wrote a wrapper function that checks if id is non-null and sets fromServer to true.